# python requests (form filling)

Tags: python-3.x

This is the link to a page 
filling forms...

https://anotepad.com/notes/2yrwpi

where I have to enter the content in the text area (say)("hello world") and then press save, but all this is to be done with python `request` module (get, post etc) 
and without the use of selenium and beautifulsoup module.

I tried something like:

```
url="https://anotepad.com/notes/2yrwpi"
txt = "Hello World"

#construct the POST request
form_data = {'btnSaveNote':'Save', 'notecontent' : txt} 

post = requests.post(url,data=form_data)
```

But that doesn't seem to be working

Please help!

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: no change occured in the notes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to *login* and post to the save url, you also need to pass the note number in the form data:

```
import requests

save = "https://anotepad.com/note/save"
txt = "Hello World"
login = "https://anotepad.com/create_account"

data = {"action": "login",
        "email": "you@whatever.com",
        "password": "xxxxxx",
        "submit": ""}

# construct the POST request
with requests.session() as s: # Use a Session object.
    s.post(login, data) # Login.

    form_data = {"number": "2yrwpi",
                 "notetype": "PlainText",
                 "noteaccess": "2",
                 "notequickedit": "false",
                 "notetitle": "whatever",
                 "notecontent": txt}

    r = s.post(save, data=form_data) # Save note.
```

`r.json()` will give you `{"message":"Saved"}` on success. Also if you want to see what notes you have, after logging in, run `s.post("https://anotepad.com/note/list").text`.

Comment: Thanks alot Sir.It worked.
But I need one more help from you,that where did you learn how you do this.What I mean is that can you give me a refernce to some book,where the complete web scrapign is explained in detail from scratch.

Thanks in advance

Comment: save = "https://anotepad.com/note/save"  ??How do you get to know that this is a saving url??