# How to use Requests to Sign into https://www.supplystore.com.au/shop/login.aspx

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have been looking at the site's requests when I log in, but I have tried to replicate them but have no luck. Could someone please help me write up some code that will allow me to use requests to log in to the site. Login URL is https://www.supplystore.com.au/shop/login.aspx The site has recaptcha v3 im pretty sure.

```
s = requests.session()
def load_task():
    login_url = 'https://www.supplystore.com.au/shop/login.aspx'
    r_login = s.get(login_url)
    soup = bs(r_login.text, 'html.parser')
    __VIEWSTATE = soup.find('input', {'name': '__VIEWSTATE'})['value']
    #print(__VIEWSTATE)
    __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR = soup.find('input', {'name': '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'})['value']
    #print(__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR)
    form_data = {'__EVENTTARGET': '',
                '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
                '__VIEWSTATE': __VIEWSTATE,
                'ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$PageContentPlaceholder$loginForm$UserName': user,
                'ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$PageContentPlaceholder$loginForm$Password': password,
                'ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$PageContentPlaceholder$loginForm$RememberMeSet': 'on',
                'ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$PageContentPlaceholder$loginForm$RedirectUrl': '/',
                'ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$PageContentPlaceholder$loginForm$Login': 'Login',
                '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR}
    headers = {
        'origin': login_url,
        'referer': 'https://www.supplystore.com.au/shop/login.aspx',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36',
        'DNT': '1',

    }

    send_r = s.post(login_url, data=form_data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438323/python-requests-form-filling
Try to read it instead.

Comment: @AdamZaft I've tried it already
https://pastebin.com/hQ3VjR2y